# SQL query to get value of another column corresponding to a max value of a column based on group by

Tags: sql, group-by, max

I have the following table:

```
ID     BLOWNUMBER    TIME            LADLE
---    ----------    ----------      -----
124      1           01/01/2012        2
124      1           02/02/2012        1
124      1           03/02/2012        0
124      2           04/01/2012        1
125      2           04/06/2012        1
125      2           01/03/2012        0
```

I want to have the `TIME` for the maximum value of `LADLE` for a group of `ID & BLOWNUMBER`.

Output required:

```
124        1       01/01/2012
124        2       04/01/2012
125        2       04/06/2012
```

Comment: That `TIME` column looks an awful lot like a **DATE** (rather than a time.....)

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... stuff like this can be very vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using SQL Server (or another engine which supports CTE's and `ROW_NUMBER`), you can use this CTE (Common Table Expression) query:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
   SELECT 
      ID, BlowNumber, [Time],
      RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, BLOWNUMBER ORDER BY [Time] DESC)
   FROM Sample
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

See this [SQL Fiddle here for an online live demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85ad8/3).

This CTE "partitions" your data by `(ID, BLOWNUMBER)`, and the `ROW_NUMBER()` function hands out numbers, starting at 1, for each of those "partitions", ordered by the `[Time]` columns (newest time value first).

Then, you just select from that CTE and use `RN = 1` to get the most recent of each data partition.

Comment: Why not just use an inner query?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sqllite (probably compatible with other DBs as well); you could do:

```
select 
    ct.id
    , ct.blownumber
    , time 
from 
    new 
    , (
        select 
            id
            , blownumber
            , max(ladle) as ldl 
        from 
            new 
        group by 
            id
            , blownumber
    ) ct
where 
    ct.id = new.id
    and ct.blownumber = new.blownumber
    and ct.ldl = new.ladle;
```